# Problems Publishing Actions with Facebook SDK for PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, publishing

I've added the following code into the "body" section:

```
<?php
  require "php-sdk/facebook.php";
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'xxxxxxxxx',
    'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie'=>true
  ));
  if(!$facebook->getUser()) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_actions'));
    echo "<script> top.location=\"".$url."\"; </script>";
    exit(0);
  }
  $params = array('photo'=>'' . site_url( $this->uri->uri_string() ) . '',
      'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken());
  $out = $facebook->api('/me/marcellusmusic:love','post',$params);
  print_r($out);
?>
```

I received the following error:

```
Uncaught OAuthException:
  Unknown path components:
    /app_marcellusmusic:love thrown in /home/content/88/4739388/html/php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1238'
```

Any advice?

Comment: I know this post is old, but I'm having the exact same problem.  Any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

What is **marcellusmusic:love**?

Maybe you should use it like this:

```
<?php
  require "php-sdk/facebook.php";
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'xxxxxxxxx',
    'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie'=>true
  ));
  if(!$facebook->getUser()) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_actions'));
    echo "<script> top.location=\"".$url."\"; </script>";
    exit(0);
  }
  $params = array('photo'=>'' . site_url( $this->uri->uri_string() ) . '',
      'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken());
  $out = $facebook->api('/me/feed','post',$params);
  print_r($out);
?>
```

I have only changed the api path.

Comment: marcellusmusic is his apps namespace and love is his custom action.  IE: Eljon Curry loves the photo on _site_.